# Insert new class into banner module [OpenCart 1.5.6]

Tags: php, opencart

I need some help with banner module from Opencart. I need to add a new div with a class between class="content-top" and class="banner0". I need this new div to enclose the group of banners. I try to add this div in banner.tpl, but the opencart enclose each div class="bannerX" into that new div. Where should I add this div? 
Thank You

http://s27.postimg.org/69p9hqtg3/screen.png

Comment: nobody know how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. At least not in the normal way.

A short explanation: In OpenCart the `banner.tpl` is used for every time a banner needs to be rendered. Therefore if You insert some code into this template, it will be rendered that many times how many banners are displayed. It could be possible to add this new `<div></div>` into the `common/content_top.tpl` around the `foreach` loop, but this could lead into problems when different modules are being rendered at this position (e.g. You render here three banner and one slideshow module). In this case all of them will be enclosed in such div.

But if You know that at the `content_top` position all You will display is a banner module then this is the way to do it (editing `common/content_top.tpl`).